# Ionic - two Toggle bars show

Tags: ionic-framework

Here is my codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwPggE
The specific HTML is:

```
  <ion-toggle>
      <div class="item">
        {{menu.form.surveyMode ? 'Survey' : 'Enforcement'}} Mode 
        <label class="toggle toggle-positive">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="menu.form.surveyMode">
          <div class="track"><div class="handle"></div></div>
        </label>
      </div>
  </ion-toggle>
```

This is showing two toggle buttons, I only need one. If I remove the `<ion-toggle>` then the button does not act as a slider but just like a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="menu.form.surveyMode" toggle-class="toggle-positive">
    {{menu.form.surveyMode ? 'Survey' : 'Enforcement'}} Mode 
</ion-toggle>
```

The above piece of code solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use this piece of code and have a look, it works absolutely fine...

```
<div class="item">
  {{menu.form.surveyMode ? 'Survey' : 'Enforcement'}} Mode
  <label style="float:right" class="toggle toggle-positive">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="menu.form.surveyMode">
    <div class="track">
      <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I've posted the answer, I think <ion-toggle> is the way to go.

Comment: gr8..this solved your problem, however the above piece of code i gave also produced the same desired results..

Comment: Thx, let me try yours. With my piece of code, if I click the button, then I am unable to slide it.

Comment: Tested yours, but its not sliding at all :(

Comment: I guess, u might have added my code inside ion-toggle tags, that's why it's not working. Plz add the above code inside ion-content tags of your code, its working absolutely fine, I checked it twice.